# UITableView Edit/Done Button

Tags: iphone, uitableview

How can I implement a button on the navigation bar whereby the user would be able to reorder & delete rows of a UITableView?

Do I have to create my own toolbar button to have the Edit/Done button for my UITableView?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just add this line in `viewDidLoad` of your `UITableViewController`

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

It will work if your table view superview is `UINavigationController`. This line will add button that will push table in edit mode and out of it.

Comment: I tried, though the button is there but it doesn't push my tableView in and out of editing mode. Is there any delegate call back I have to handle?

Comment: is your view controller a subclass of uitableviewcontroller

Comment: I just made my ViewController a subclass of UITableViewController and it worked. But how do I implement the function of allowing the user to rearrange the rows?

Comment: All is well now. I need to set `cell.showsReorderControl = TRUE;` and implement `- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` & `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath ` method

Comment: If my answer helped you to solve the problem don't forget to accept it. TY

Comment: I'm using a UIViewController with a nested table view as well. This is a great post that helped me (NOTE: Don't use the native "Edit" button setting. Make sure the button is set to "Custom")
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158169/uibarbuttonitem-changing-title-not-working

Answer (score 21):

What's generally done is you create your own custom BarbuttonItem and then assign this button as right navigation bar button item:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Edit"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                              target:self 
                                                              action:@selector(toggleEdit)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;   
[barButtonItem release];
```

Here's the toggleEdit method:

```
-(void)toggleEdit{
          [self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.editing animated:YES]; 

          if (self.tableView.editing) 
              [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"]; 
          else 
             [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
UIButton *btnname=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[btnname setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,110,35)];
[btnname setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18]];
[btnname setTitle: @"Delete" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[btnname setTitleColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xCC0707)        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnname.backgroundColor=UIColorFromRGB(0xE6E7E8);
btnname.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
[btnname addTarget:self
            action:@selector(toggleEdit)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
UIBarButtonItem *barItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnname];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barItem;


-(void)toggleEdit{
    [self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.editing animated:YES];

    if (self.tableView.editing)
         [btnname setTitle: @"Done" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    else
         [btnname setTitle: @"Delete" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a Swift version I used:

```
func clickedEditButton(button: UINavigationItem) {
    tableView.setEditing(!tableView.editing, animated: true)

    if tableView.editing {
        button.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Done"
    } else {
        button.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Edit"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your button to switch between the blue "Done" color and the plain "Edit" color, you can set the rightBarButtonItem to either UIBarButtonItemStyleDone for  blue, or UIBarButtonItemStylePlain for plain like this

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleDone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you need to initialize the title first. By storyBoard,

[image]

after that,

```
@IBAction func editBtnPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        tableView.setEditing(!tableView.isEditing, animated: true)

        if tableView.isEditing {
            self.editButton.title = "Done"
        } else {
            self.editButton.title = "Edit"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is being used in the case where on non-UITableViewController UIViewController has an outlet to the UITableView in question.

As mentioned above, you cannot change the values in the bar button item, particularly if it's a system item. If you desire, you can create the two items and have them available in ivars (like the UITableViewController). It's not really that much execution time to create a new one though, especially if it may never be used.

**Swift 5**

```
@IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

@IBAction func toggleTableEdit(sender:UIBarButtonItem) {
    table.setEditing(!table.isEditing, animated: true)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: (table.isEditing) ? .done : .edit, target: self, action: #selector(toggleTableEdit(sender:)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Nekto's answer is correct, you need to add this line to your `viewDidLoad` implementation:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
```

However, this new "Edit" button can work not only with subclasses of `UITableViewController`, but with any subclass of `UIViewController`. You just have to implement the `setEditing` method yourself.

For example, here is how it works in a `UIViewController` with a tableView:

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    tableView.isEditing = editing // <-- toggle the tableView's editing mode
}
```