# Setting UIBarButtonItem not changing title, changing only style

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` in the top right which says 'Edit'. When clicked, this code is called - I know so because the button is emboldened. However, the button's title does not change. Here is my code:

```
 // set to not editing and change buttons
        [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
        [doneButton setTitle:@"Done"];
        [doneButton setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
```

Edit 2:

The following code is doing what I want, however the first time I click the edit button, nothing happens.

```
-(void)editButton:(id)sender {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(edit:)];

}

-(void) edit:(UIBarButtonItem *) barBtnItem
{
    // if not editing
    if (![self isEditing])
    {
        [self setEditing:YES];
        barBtnItem.tag = 1;
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    }
    else
    {
        [self setEditing:NO];
        barBtnItem.tag = 0;
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(edit:)];
barButton.tag = 0;
barButton.possibleTitles = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Edit", @"Done", nil];
```

Just change state according to click. simple thing.

```
-(void) edit:(UIBarButtonItem *) barBtnItem
{
     if (barBtnItem.tag == 0)
    {
       barBtnItem.tag = 1;
       [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    }
    else
    {
        barBtnItem.tag = 0;
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is doing what I want so far (I modified it slightly). However, on the click, nothing happens. My modified code is in the original post.

Answer (score 4):

What about this:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

I think it does pretty much what you want it to do.

It changes to "Done" when tapped, and then back to "Edit" when tapped again. Furthermore it sets the view controllers editing property accordingly.

Comment: Yes, this functionality is built in.

Comment: This is the correct way to do what you want, you can mark this as the correct answer, the others are hacks.

Comment: var saveButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItem.Save, target:self, action:"savePressed:")
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via code as well as follows

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doneClicked:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton;
```

Comment: This initializes it. OP wants to change title *after* it has already been created and displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution: Just change the BarButtonItem's identifier to custom.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not change the need for the customization of the Title property.

Comment: This helps me.  I'm always forgetting that if I set the type to anything other than custom in IB, it will ignore my attempts to set the title.

Answer (score 0):

Change type from System:Edit to Custom

Answer (score -1):

From "title" property on the [UIBarButtonItem reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBarItem/title)

> You should set this property before adding the item to a bar. The
>   default value is nil.

Check [this qn also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158169/uibarbuttonitem-changing-title-not-working?rq=1)