# Set Title to UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have `UIBarButtonItem` and whenever I try to set title to the button, its not working.

```
@IBOutlet weak var barButton: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     barButton.title = "AB"
}
```

But if I try to create Action of `UIBarButtonItem` and then do sender.setTitle() then it works. But not at `viewDidLoad`. I don't want to set title when user taps on the button.

Comment: For this you need to programatically create UIBarButton on view did load.

Comment: @DheerajD Hi, Can you please explain why it cannot be done by this way ?

Comment: UIBarButton allocates when view controller loads and you cannot change its title on run time and if you want to change its title so you need to allocate new barbutton and assign it to left or right item.

Comment: You can also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547284/setting-uibarbuttonitem-not-changing-title-changing-only-style

Comment: You can change the title of the barButton in viewDidLoad, test passed on Xcode 8.2 (Swift 3).

Comment: @bubuxu Can you please explain how ? Even I'm on Xcode 8.2 (Swift 3)

Comment: @Nitesh please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Change title or image and then resign it back to navigationItem:

```
class AnotherViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let barButton = myBarButton
        barButton?.title = "Anther Title"
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton

    }
}
```

Apple document: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibaritem/1616412-title

> You should set this property before adding the item to a bar. The default value is nil.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an IBOutlet for the barButton, why not just set the title in the storyboard? I think this is the easiest way unless you have some other reason for doing it programmatically.

[image]

Comment: Alright, well it would be helpful to clarify that you only could use programming methods, since your title is just "set title to UIBarButtonItem"

Answer (score 0):

When I try this, it works. Maybe there is a bug with Xcode, delete your button and connections then try again.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var barButton: UIBarButtonItem!
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       barButton.title = "MyButton"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
@IBOutlet weak var barButton: UIBarButtonItem! {
  didSet {
    barButton.title = "AB"
 }
}
```