# Can't change UINavigation Bar Item title

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have a uinavigation bar, and on it a bar button item and i named the title as "Start", when i press it i wanted it to change to "Stop", What i did was

```
      _startButton.title = @"Stop"
```

where "_startButton" is @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *startButton;

It was working fine before but the button got deleted by mistake and i made it again and relinked it with my code and now it stopped working. I don't know how to let it work. Can anyone please help me with this? I know it seems something very very simple but its not changing and i have no idea why. :-/

Comment: remove the link and link it again.

Comment: My guess, without seeing the storyboard, is that you don't have the outlet connected to the new button.

Comment: I did that but its still not changing the title, I changed the name of the button IBOutlet and put a different name but even then its not changing the title :-/

Comment: @Kevin I did hook up the IBAction

Comment: The Button works perfectly fine and does a task that it starts the game and timer starts but the title of the button that i am changing is not happening :-/

Comment: Seems like your answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158169/uibarbuttonitem-changing-title-not-working

Comment: @Justafinger OMG!!! Thank you solo Much!!! IT WORKSSSSSS :D :D :D

Comment: @Justafinger Same Thing is happening with my timer also. My timer is also a bar button item but i just want to change the title as the time changes using nastier. Title is not changing. Can you please help?