# Setting the text of a BarButtonItem on the NavigationBar?

Tags: swift, xcode

Id like to remove an icon and add text to BarButtomItem, but im not sure how to do it. here is my currrent code:

```
let logoutButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Action, target: self, action: #selector(SettingsViewController.logout))
        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(logoutButton, animated: false)
```

I thought i could just do `UIBarButtonItem(text: "sign out", ...` but I guess that doesn't work.

Comment: you can add a UIButton as the customView of the UIBarButtonItem and set the title of the UIButton

Comment: Changed the text. Remove the button. Then add the button back.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14694997/2108547

Answer (score 1):

you can connect your UIBarButtonItem from the UI.

[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var logoutButton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

It should look like this when you connect it.

Setting of that button can look like this

[image]

And finally put this line to ViewDidLoad func:

```
   //Logout button
    logoutButton.title = "Sign out" //This is the button title
```

:) It should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but in case somebody else's need this, you can actually create a bar button item with just text:

```
let logoutButton:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Sign out",
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain,
                                   target:self,
                                   action:#selector(SettingsViewController.logout))
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(logoutButton, animated:false)
```